# Elastic search query in array of json object

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

So, I have a `metadata` data field in my index which is in the following format.

```json
metadata: [
 {
    "key": "type",
    "value": "animal"
 },
 {
    "key": "animal",
    "value": "cat"
 }
]
```

The array can have thousands of objects, and I cannot change the structure of this field.
My client application requests the server with `key=value` format. How do I write elastic search query to get the result?

Request query `type=animal` should return only 1st object from the array **(not 2nd)**.
Request query `animal=cat` should return only 2nd object from the array **(not 1st)**.
Request query `type=cat` should not return anything.

How can it be achieved? I am worn out trying to figure out the correct query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you have to return only the matching object from the array based on the query.

On the basis of [Elasticsearch Array docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/array.html)

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
> each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
> need to be able to do this then you should use the nested datatype
> instead of the object datatype.

If you want to query on each object of the array and return only the specific object from the array, you need to use a nested query with inner_hits. But for using the nested query, you have to create a new index with nested mapping

Adding a working example with index mapping, index data, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
PUT <index-name>
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "metadata":{
        "type":"nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
POST <index-name>/_doc/1
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "key": "type",
      "value": "animal"
    },
    {
      "key": "animal",
      "value": "cat"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST <index-name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "metadata",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "metadata.key": "animal"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"inner_hits" : {
          "metadata" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.6931471,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "70711376",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "metadata",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : 0.6931471,
                  "_source" : {
                    "value" : "cat",
                    "key" : "animal"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: @paradox its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)